# Java 8 programming: Reading a .ini-file and trying to get rid of newline-characters

Tags: java, newline, ini

I'm using Netbeans IDE. For a school project I need to read an .ini-file, and get some specific information.

The reason I'm not using ini4j:

- I have a section that has key values which are the same
- I have sections that have no key-value inputs that I have to read information from

Example ini-file:

```
[Section]

Object1 5 m

number = 12

Object2 6 m
;Comment followed by white line

number = 1\

4
```

`\` means the next command or white lines need to be ignored
So the last part of the ini file actually means: `number = 14`

My task: I need to store the oject names with the corresponding length (meters) and number into a single string like this:
Object1 has length 1m and number 12

My problem:
I use a scanner with delimiter `//Z` to store the whole file into a single String.
This works (if I print out the String it gives the example above).

I've tried this code:

```
String file = file.replaceAll("(\\.)(\\\\)(\\n*)(\\.)","");
```

If I try to only remove the newlines:

```
String file = file.replace("\n","");
System.out.println(file);
```

I get an empty output.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Or pick a superior format like yaml, hocon, JSON ... even XML IMO is more flexible and superior to ini files

Comment: \ usually means that the next line is part of this line. I would double-check your specification.

Comment: Or just try my answer, it works even though it has downvotes...

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ini is a specification with a formal grammar. Adhere to the grammar, then use standard libraries.

Comment: @AdamGent ini has one big advantage (and a lot of disadvantages I agree): it is very easy to understand and it is standardized, many users are too... challenged by other formats for simple configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to esacpe `\` in Java Strings *and* in regular expressions, so you need to escape them *twice*. This means if you want to get rid of empty lines you have to write it like this:

```
file = file.replaceAll("\\n+", "\n");
```

If you know that a `\` at the end of a line is always followed by an empty line then this means that it is actually followed by 2 new line characters which would give the following:

```
file = file.replaceAll("\\\\\\n\\n", "");
```

or (it's the same):

```
file = file.replaceAll("\\\\\\n{2}", "");
```

`\\\\` will result in `\\` in the regex, so it matches `\` and `\\n` will become `\n` and match the new line character.

And as mentioned by @Bohemian it would be better to fix the ini-file. Standards make everything easier. If you insist you could use your own file extension, because it is actually another format.

It is also possible to write a regular expression that directly extracts you the values:

```
file = file.replaceAll("\\\\\\n\\n", "");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^ *([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) *= *(.+?) *$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // left side of = (already trimmed)
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // right side of = (already trimmed)
}
```

It's easier than reading lines one by one, but performance could be worse. Anyway usually this is not an issue because ini files tend to be small.

Comment: @EJP No, 4 to match the \ and 2 from the \\n ... i don't get the downvotes, it is correct. This is Java+regex, not just regex.

Comment: I soon stop anwering, people having no clue are downvoting all the time and if they base their answer on mine they don't even upvote it... which I always do. Not chasing the checkmark, I don't care about that... but seriously people just come look at it... oooh i never saw that before.... let's downvote it. At least give me a **reason** and I could correct it... if there were a mistake.

Comment: @maraca-First of all, I am not the downvoter. Next, it's really difficult to guess the problem with your answer & face the heat with unknown reasons not mentioned. This is the way how this community behaves, you can't do much except from doing your job/role! I am too a victim of this. Let's start bearing this,if you've to help question-posters...

Comment: @shekharsuman are you EJP? Then I'm sorry accusing you. When I am looking for answers then often all good answers have low marks, it's a pain to find them someone just gave a generic answer like the other here and it got a ridiculous amount of upvotes. And if there are 20 answers I might miss it completely. It's just sad that so many good answers (and I'm not talking about mine here) get burried by those generic answers that really weren't that hard to find.

Comment: @maraca- I am speaking on my own behalf. Let us serve the community and think those immature downvotes "Rest In Peace". This is what I want you to feel,just serve,with no `things-in-return` thinking. This community is really as much a dangerous place as good as it is! We have to try adapting to its standard.

Answer (score 2):

You are on right way. But logic is on wrong place. You actually need \n for your logic to recognize new value in your ini file.

I would suggest that you do not read entire file to the string. Why? You will still work with line from file one by one. Now you read whole file to string then split to single strings to analyze. Why not just read file with scanner line by line and analyze these lines as they come?

And when you work with individual line then simply skip empty ones. And it solves your issue.

Comment: ... almost, you need to remove trailing \ and maybe only if they are followed by an empty line, then you would need a lookahead of 1 line. But yes it is a possibility, especially if you want to parse it at the same time.